# How can testers recieve app updates in crashlytics beta

Tags: android, crashlytics-android, crashlytics-beta

I have a nightly build set up which deploys to crashlytics beta every night, but for each apk I upload I have to manually add testers, how can testers just receive the most recently uploaded apk to crashlytics beta instead of having to add them every time, it completely misses the point of continuous delivery.

Comment: Mike from Fabric here. How are you building? Also, are these new testers you're adding each time?

Comment: @MikeBonnell this is the script that i run `./gradlew clean assembleNightlyRelease crashlyticsUploadDistributionNightlyRelease` , testers are not automatically added to the latest version, do I have to manually add them?

Comment: Awesome, you just need to include the group alias that you want to distribute to each build. Using:

ext.betaDistributionGroupAliases="my-best-tester-group-alias"

You could also use a sharelink.

Comment: @MikeBonnel so all i have to do is write `ext. betaDistribution=my-aliases` in android closure? and the task will automatically add testers in that group alias?

Comment: Just add it to the built type or flavor you're using for the distribution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mike from Fabric here.

You can add tester group aliases or email address into your app's gradle build type or flavor that you're distributing. [From the documentation](https://docs.fabric.io/android/beta/gradle.html), add the group alias, or aliases using:

```
ext.betaDistributionGroupAliases="my-best-testers"
```

or a comma-separated file of the group aliases:

```
ext.betaDistributionGroupAliasesFilePath=group_aliases.txt
```

You can also specify specific individual testers via a comma separated file of testers: (Use the following format: first name, last name, email address.)

```
ext.betaDistributionEmailsFilePath="beta_distribution_emails.txt"
```

or their email addresses:

```
ext.betaDistributionEmails="BetaUser@yourcompany.com, BetaUser2@yourcompany.com"
```

Comment: Do you have details about the format of the text file containing tester email addresses? I have a single email in a text file, nothing else, but sadly the builds are landing in Fabric without an invite sent. Or any tips for debugging this?

Comment: @DamienDiehl I edited my answer to include the format of first name, last name, email address

Comment: @MikeBonnell Thanks, that helps. I also had my file in the root of the app module instead of the root of the project, moving it fixed the relative path I was using.